.NET MAUI BLE app not showing any services
I am trying to develop an application that connects to a BLE device (ESP32) and read the data sent by it using Plugin.BLE and .NET MAUI.
BTPage.xaml.cs
using Plugin.BLE;
using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Contracts;

namespace bleTestApp;

public partial class BTPage : ContentPage
{
    private IAdapter _adapter;
    private List<IDevice> _devices;
    private List<IService> _services;
    public BTPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _adapter = CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;
        _devices = new List<IDevice>();
        _services = new List<IService>();
    }

    private async void scan_btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var devices = _adapter.GetSystemConnectedOrPairedDevices().ToList();
        
        lst.ItemsSource = devices;
    }
    private async void lst_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedDevice = e.Item as IDevice;
        if (selectedDevice != null)
        {
            _adapter?.ConnectToDeviceAsync(selectedDevice);

            await DisplayAlert("Connection done!", $"Connected to {selectedDevice.Name}", "Ok");

            var services = await selectedDevice.GetServicesAsync();

            foreach (var service in services) { 
                _services.Add(service);
            }

            if (_services != null) {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new ServicePage(_services));
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("No Services", "no services available", "Ok");
            }
        }
    }
}

servicePage.xaml.cs
using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Contracts;

namespace bleTestApp;

public partial class ServicePage : ContentPage
{
    private IDevice _device;
    private List<IService> _services;
    private List<string> _serviceNames;
    public ServicePage(List<IService> services)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _services = services;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        foreach (var service in _services) { 
            _serviceNames.Add(service.Name);
        }
        serviceLst.ItemsSource = _serviceNames;
    }


    private async void serviceLst_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var service_checked = e.Item as IService;
        var characteristic = await service_checked.GetCharacteristicAsync(Guid.Parse("beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"));

        var data_bytes = await characteristic.ReadAsync();

        await DisplayAlert("Data", $"{data_bytes}", "Ok");
    }
}

I am able to connect to the device(ESP32) but the app is not showing any services, also it is navigating to the other page, that means the services are not NULL.

Also I am able to get all the services using the nrfConnect app.
Help appreciated!

Hello @Shubhanbar Pande,
I worked on Xamarin BLE about a year ago to retrieve heart rate data from a Bluetooth device using Xamarin. You can find the reference link to my code here: Stack Overflow Link. In my code, I implemented functionality to discover all services and characteristics of the device. Please take a look at the code when you get a chance.

Sure, I will definitely check it, thanks for the help!

Why don't you use debugger to watch _services variable to see what are in there? I think the issue is on the servicePage.xaml which doesn't show your items as expected.
